# Xcode GLKit printing Text on GLKView without using UIImages

Tags: xcode, glkit

I have an app, its a small game using opengles with GLKit.
No im wondering how it works when i want to draw text on 
my screen (if it is possible).

How can i do it?

i draw all of my game objects using images (wrapped in some kind
of sprite). its possible to scale, to move, and to rotate.
everything works fine.

but finding out how it works to print text on that glkview
gets me deep inside of problems ^^

I dont want to use uiimages cause i also dont know how 
to present uiimages on a glkview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do what you want:

1) Have an image with all the text glyphs you need in it. For example, if your application is in English, you'd have the 26 uppercase and 26 lowercase letters in the image. Upload that texture to the GPU and use the proper texture coordinates or `glSubTexImage2d()` to pull out the glyphs you need. (It's not clear to me if this is what you meant by not wanting a UIImage. It doesn't have to be a UIImage, though that's probably easiest.)

2) Every time you need to display text, draw it on the CPU on the fly, and upload the entire word, phrase, or sentence as a texture. You could create a `CGBitmapContext` and use Core Graphics to draw text to it. Then upload it using `glTexImage2D()`.

3) Get the individual glyphs out of the fonts and draw directly using the bezier curves that make up the glyphs. This allows for 3D extrusion, too. However, this option is the most time consuming to code and probably least performant. It also involves dealing with the many small problems that fonts have (like degenerate segments, and incorrect winding orders). IF you want to go down this path, I think maybe [Core Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFontRef/Reference/reference.html) can help.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two clean ways to do this, depending on your requirements.

While documentation advises against compositing over a `CAEAGLLayer` (GLKView), it works quite well, at least in recent iOS versions, when transparent content is layered on top of the CAEAGLLayer.  For example, try dropping a UITextView, with opaque set to false and a **clear** background color, on top of a GLKView in your Storyboard in Interface Builder in the Apple GLKit template or your app. In my test on an iPhone 5, frame rendering time remained around 1ms, even while scrolling in the text view.  If your text needs are static, or you don't want the user to interact with the text, use CATextLayer as a child layer of your EAGLLayer instead of a view.

The second approach is to render the text into a texture. You can then composite the text onto your view by disabling the depth buffer and rendering the texture on a full screen rectangle. Look at `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to see how to render to an offscreen image with Quartz. `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` allows you to retrieve the UIImage to use as a texture.